# How to exert boolean operator in Arrays c#?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, boolean

How to exert boolean operator in Arrays c#.
I have three 3D arrays same size,I want to exert boolean operator on two arrays and keep the result in array3.
For example:

```
int[, ,] array1 = new int[,,] { { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } }, 
                             { { 7, 8, 9 }, { 10, 11, 12 } } };
int[, ,] array2 = new int[,,] { { { 1, 1, 1 }, { 0, 0, 0 } }, 
                             { { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 } } };
int [, ,] array3 = new int[4,3]; 
result = array1 (AND operator) array2;
```

The expected result:

```
array3 = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 0, 0, 0 } },{ { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 } };
```

My question is there any way to implement boolean exert on two arrays without accessing array elements?

Thank you for advance.

Comment: Are you saying you want to mask the first array with the second?

Comment: Yes, masking(not very well expressed the problem)

Comment: the && is logical operator, it returns either true or false, how do you except 3 && 1 return 3 ?!

Comment: `without accessing array elements?` you want to compare elements of an 2 array without accessing elements of an array? Are you asking for a built in library function or is this a trick question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good news is that from framework 4.0 there is [Zip method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx):

> Enumerable.Zip Method Applies a specified
>   function to the corresponding elements of two sequences, which
>   produces a sequence of the results.

For single-dimensional arrays it is straightforward:

```
        int[] array1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        int[] array2 = new int[] { 0, 1, 0 };

        var zipped = array1.Zip(array2, (first, second) => second == 0 ? 0 : first);
        //zipped = {0, 2, 0}
```

The bad news is that multidimensional arrays don't implement IEnumerable, but you can use Zip with jagged arrays. You can try something like this:

```
        int[][] jagged1 = new int[][]
                {
                    new int[] {1,2,3},
                    new int[] {4,5,6},
                    new int[] {7,8,9}
                };

        int[][] jagged2 = new int[][]
                {
                    new int[] {1,1,1},
                    new int[] {0,0,0},
                    new int[] {0,0,0}
                };

        var zipped = jagged1.Zip(jagged2, (firstArray, secondArray)                             
                        => firstArray.Zip(secondArray, 
                              (first, second) => second == 0 ? 0 : first)
                     );

        //zipped = {{1,2,3}, {0,0,0}, {0,0,0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure what you mean, but:

```
int[,,] array3 = new int[array1.GetLength(0), array1.GetLength(1), array1.GetLength(2)];

for (int x = 0; x < array1.GetLength(0); ++x)
    for (int y = 0; y < array1.GetLength(1); ++y)
        for (int z = 0; z < array1.GetLength(2); ++z)
            array3[x, y, z] = (array2[x, y, z] != 0) ? array1[x, y, z] : 0;
```

If array2[x,y,z] is not zero, set array3[x,y,z] to array1[x,y,z] otherwise set array3[x,y,z] to 0.

Is that what you meant?